# webpack4 rebuild cost too much memory

Tags: memory, webpack, webpack-dev-server

After webpack-dev-server had bootstraped, the memory cost 900M. When I change a little code, webpack rebuilding will cost 300M - 400M memory. However the extra memory will be released after one minuete.

So if I often update code, the nodejs memory will  overflow stack.

The error message like the pic.
[image: the error message]

I didn't use hash in development mode. And there was no problem when use webpack3.

Comment: Sounds like a webpack bug (or a bug with one of the plugins) where things get maintained in the "old heap" rather than being evicted early from the "new heap" of V8 (the JS engine). I recommend opening this at Webpack's issue tracker - as isolated as possible.

Comment: OK, I will open an issue for this problem. Thanks